# Angular Highcharts addPoint in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, highcharts, mean-stack

I am creating an application in which it reads the json data from api and from this data create a charts in angular.

Module I using for chart is 'angular-highcharts'

onClick point is adding on graph is perfectly fine but what I want is to update graph and add points dynamically in the loop.

**Graph.Component.html**

```
<div [chart]="chart"></div>
<div *ngFor="let post of posts | slice:2">
  {{ format( post.time, post.acceleration ) }}
</div>
```

**Graph.Component.js**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AccelerationService } from '../services/acceleration.service';

import { Chart } from '../../../node_modules/angular-highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-graph',
  templateUrl: './graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graph.component.css'],
  providers: [AccelerationService]
})

export class GraphComponent implements OnInit {

  chart = new Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        marginRight: 20,
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Acceleration w.r.t Time'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 50
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Acceleration (m/s²)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Acceleration',
        data: [
          [1507621680006, -1.309661],
          [1507621681001, -1.309661],
          [1507621681006, -0.5938691],
          [1507621682001, 0.4505874],
        ]
    }]
});

  posts: Post[];

  constructor(private accelerationService: AccelerationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.accelerationService.getPosts().subscribe((posts) => {
      this.posts = posts;
    });

  }

  format(time, acc) {
    var startTime = new Date();
    var parts = time.match(/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+).(\d+) (AM|PM)/);
    if (parts) {
        var hours = parseInt(parts[1]),
            minutes = parseInt(parts[2]),
            seconds = parseInt(parts[3]),
            milliseconds = parseInt(parts[4]),
            tt = parts[5];
        if (tt === 'PM' && hours < 12) hours += 12;
        startTime.setHours(hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
    }    
    var milliseconds = startTime.getTime();

    return this.chart.addPoint( [milliseconds,acc] );
  }
}

interface Post {
  time: TimeRanges,
  acceleration: string
}
```

Comment: Standard Highcharts API provides `addPoint` method for this: http://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

It seems that this method is also available in angular-highcharts: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts

Comment: Yes addPoint method is available, but it stops working when I called format(time, acc) in ngFor. However if I call it onClick it's working fine.

Comment: What I want is to add point automatically on graph not thorough onClick

Comment: Please try to track down where the source of the problem is. Maybe you are trying to access the chart before it's created? Try debugging to pin point the problem. If you have a live demo that you could share or another way to recreate the problem, that would be great.